# Howto export module with it submodules in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I want to create a Velbus (home automation) library to import in any project with Node.JS.
However, there are plenty of function (sometime 6 or more) on each kind of Velbus modules, so I want to split my actual library into submodules (primitives_blind.js, primitives_relay.js, primitives_tempSensor.js, etc.)
I can import them in my main library VelbusLib.js, but I don't know how to allow a user to only import my main module, but use function from submodules.

Example :
primitives_blind.js

```js
function blindUP(adr, part) { ... }
function blindDOWN(adr, part) { ... }
function blindStatus(adr, part) { ... }
module.exports = { blindUP, blindDOWN, blindStatus }
```

VelbusLib.js

```js
const blind = require('./primitives_blind.js')
```

index.js (an App)

```js
const velbusLib = require('./VelbusLib.js')
...
velbusLib.blindUP(0x40, 1) // blind.blindUP() not wanted, because user have to import all submodules
```

Of course, it's not possible to export function imported

```js
module.exports = {
    CheckSum,
    Cut,
    // blindUP or blind.blindUP aren't possible
```

A small schema is often better than a long discuss :
[image]
Can someone explain to me the "State-of-the-art" about this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, **it appears that's not implicite** to have many submodules (ModA, ModB, ModC) and import a module ModX in an app "APP" and use import ModA, ModB, ModC from it.

However, it's possible to export from ModX, some import from ModA or ModB or ModC :

In ModX.js:

```js
import {actionA1, actionA2} from './ModA'
import ModB from './ModB'
import * from './ModC'
...
export { actionA2, ModB }
```

Then in app.js:

```js
import ModX from './ModX'
...
let Foo = actionA2(something)
let Bar = ModB.actionB(somethingElse)
```

Thanks [@bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for his correction

Comment: Sure this should be possible. To use `import { ModA, ModB, ModC } from 'ModX';`, the ModX module must export these of course. Can you [edit] this post to show excerpts from App, ModX and ModA?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking for [object literal spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const blind = require('./primitives_blind.js')
module.exports = {
    CheckSum,
    Cut,
    ...blind,
};
```

which essentially does the same as

```
const blind = require('./primitives_blind.js')
module.exports = {
    CheckSum,
    Cut,
    blindUP: blind.blindUP,
    blindDOWN: blind.blindDOWN,
    blindStatus: blind.blindStatus,
};
```

However, since you were asking for the state of the art: use ES6 module syntax for the whole library, not CommonJS `module.exports`! With that, it would be

```
export * from './primitives_blind.js';
```

Comment: well, I've tried to be up to date and changed all my project with ES6 modules rather CommonJS one's. It tooks me long time and an headhache!